# java.io.InvalidObjectException with JMX MXBean with CompositeData

Tags: jmx, mbeans

I am trying to publish an MXBean to JMX but I am getting the following stack when I start the program and the bean is being published:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Do not know how to make a javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType from a CompositeData: no method from(CompositeData); no constructor has @ConstructorProperties annotation; does not have a public no-arg constructor; not an interface
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.invalidObjectException(OpenConverter.java:1403)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.makeCompositeBuilder(OpenConverter.java:891)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.checkReconstructible(OpenConverter.java:897)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeBuilderCheckGetters.applicable(OpenConverter.java:1034)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter$CompositeConverter.makeCompositeBuilder(OpenConverter.java:868)
        ... 48 more
```

Now I now that MXBeans are only supposed use OpenMbean types as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html) but my class is only using `java.lang.String` and `javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData`, so I do not know why it is failing. The interface is:

```
import javax.management.MXBean;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData;

@MXBean
public interface JmxAdministrationApi {

    String synchronize(CompositeData clientInfo);

}
```

It is worth noting that the bean was being published correctly until I added the `CompositeData` parameter (i.e. with no parameters), and only then did this error occur.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Edit: also, we are using Spring JMX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `CompositeData` directly even though the documentation sounds like you should. The `MXBean` will take care of converting a proprietary data type into a `CompositeData` instance and back automatically.

Take a look at the samples provided in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/mxbeans.html) to see how you should use `@ConstructorProperties` annotation to make your data type play nicely with composite data and MXBeans.

-JB-

Comment: Thanks, using @ConstructorProperties on a bean works. Is nicer too! (Apologies for the slow reply by the way, I had an extended weekend)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer ! Java documentation on JMX is not well explained, I was struggling with creating my own CompositeData but it never worked. This solution is simple, clean and works like a charm !